# Transform MySQL select to Criteria API

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have the following select statement in MySQL (sorry for the column/tables names):

```
SELECT a1.* FROM A a1
LEFT JOIN A a2
ON a1.DD_ID = a2.DD_ID
and a1.PRD = a2.PRD
AND a1.VN < a2.VN
LEFT JOIN B bb
ON a1.id = cc.del_id
WHERE a2.DD_ID is null
AND bb.del_id is null;
```

Here are the entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"DD_ID", "VN", "PRD"})})
public class A
    implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "VN", nullable = false)
    private Short vn;

    @Column(name = "PRD", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String prd;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DD_ID", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private DD dd;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "A")
    private Set<B> bs;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object pOther)
    {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
       ...
    }

    // getters and setters
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B
    implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEL_ID", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private A a;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object pOther)
    {
        ...
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

and I want to implement it using Criteria API, but I have troubles implementing the **self left join** from the statement.

Any suggestions?

Comment: JPQL and Criteria operate around classes and fields. They do not use table and column names. You don't seem to have provided the classes/fields, so not sure how you expect someone to guess what the class looks like and what its relations look like ...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Point taken